# Let's help chat rooms that want to self-moderate do so better

Tags: discussion, chat

We have the kick-mute system in place already for ROs able to warn/temporarily remove a nuisance user from their room. "Kicking" a user gets a progressively further removal of that user's privilege to chat for a certain amount of time (in three stages).

After three kicks (in various ways), the mods get an "alert".

I'm pondering a 4th stage (new idea): allow the kick-mute to be 2 hours until a moderator can investigate.

Idea's all up in the air, but what say all?

Comment: You mean 2 hours or until a mod can investigate whichever comes first? Or 2 hours before a mod will even look at it?

Comment: @codeMagic there's more mods active in chat then there has been before. No reason we should be though... let's delegate "control".

Comment: *' let's delegate "control"'* I'm all for this and anything that improves chat and gives ROs more power to handle their respective rooms. I'm just not entirely sure I understand how the proposal will work exactly

Comment: So you're suggesting a fourth kick-mute kicks for 2 hours, rather that whatever it caps at right now (I think 30 minutes)?

Comment: *Just asking*, If the 3rd vote alerts a mod, then why can't the mod take the required step? Wouldn't it invalidate the need for a 4th stage? :/

Comment: @davidism yes - that's a wild idea suggestion

Comment: I think codeMagic's first comment was based on _"allow the kick-mute to be 2 hours until a moderator can investigate."_ which, as I read it, says that the mods will investigate _after_ the two hours. But at the same time, it could just be missing an "or" in there.

Comment: If it takes 3 kicks, obviously the RO's are not in control and mod intervention is needed. A persistant user that gets kicked and returns cannot (historically speaking) be controlled by a RO.

Comment: Before we take any decision on this I think we have to take the outcome of [Toward a philosophy of Chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat) into account.

Comment: related [on parent meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266073/222299) **full disclosure** my own question

Answer (score 11):

I am glad that the kick-mute is being discussed, because it hasn't been covered much on mSO since it was introduced.

Kick-mute is a jarring user experience for the one receiving it, and it only serves to escalate a situation which was already in need of deescalation. This creates a tailspin that the room deals with. Eventually once chaos has ensued a moderator enters and has absolutely no clue what happened - it would take them hours to figure out the history of the room (sometimes there is months of history associated with events).

Moderators don't have hours to read the transcript of rooms back to the inception of a user's interaction with that room. Also, it is complicated to look for the history of interaction when there has been deletion of content from that user by previous action.

These issues are the reason why I believe we need to address two facets here:

- **moderators need help from RO's using the feature to understand what was going on**
- **the kick-mute needs to be stronger and have more oversight**

Prior to the kick-mute feature RO's would cast a custom flag for moderators with a nice explanation and then patiently wait. To be honest this worked rather well, and simply binning messages bypasses most conflict with users who are intent on being hostile - in extreme cases gallery mode is available.

With the inclusion of kick-mute the custom flag message signal is being lost. Escalation almost always happens after one kick-mute (stats?) from my observation - you can't just have one. Which is to say that *if a user has to be removed from a room for 1 minute, they basically just need to go. And if being removed from the room for 1 minute was a valid solution, they didn't need to go at all.*

Proposal for helping Room Owners help Moderators help Room Owners:

- kick-mute requires a custom message to use which triggers an automatic moderator flag
- users are removed from room and cannot return until the flag is handled
- duration is now based on moderator review
- there is no escalation

Proposal for increasing accountability for deleted content

- allow room owners to see a history of flagged messages and the flag's conclusion in a view somewhere for their room only (and also for moderators for all rooms)

Comment: But if kick-mute requires a message it is basically the same as flag for moderator (which you do on a message, btw, so you get some context). The only distinction in the mod-dashboard-flag-list can be that the flag was raised by an RO and should probably get on the high-priority queue (if that exist) or routed to a dedicated mod. With *there is no escalation* you're looking at the bright side of chat ;).

Comment: I'm all in for de-escalation. Do you think there is an option to de-escalate WITHOUT mod-intervention. Maybe that requires a sociological, psychological, group dynamics and human-interaction training/coaching/guidance but it is more to equip RO's with some extra info before they go the mod route.

Comment: @rene I added a answer about this.

Comment: "*Kick-mute is a jarring user experience for the one receiving it, and it only serves to escalate a situation which was already in need of deescalation.*" I've been kicked within five minutes the first time I joined the php room (you know, I wanted some hat...) My reaction was to pause, think about what just happened. When I joined back I was much more composed. Since then I have started joining the room often. My being kicked in fact helped me understanding the room.

Comment: @rene - Trust me, I have seen some of the dark aspects of chat. We had one of our members receive a death threat recently. Repeatedly kicking was what made that situation escalate far beyond where it should have been. The user who did the threatening was just coming off a 1 year ban that day. So I am not idealizing this, I have real world examples for why escalation is not good. A single kick still removes the user from the room, it just doesn't cause an increase in engagement between that user and the room when it is once and not three times in a row.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - You could also have just been told what was inappropriate and had your message binned. Further, it is hat season and chat rooms should be slightly more tolerant of things like that. I am not sure why certain room owners are under the impression the room belongs to them. It is a Stack Overflow chat room. You didn't need to be removed from the room.

Comment: "*I am not sure why certain room owners are under the impression the room belongs to them*".. maybe because they're titled room **owners** :p joking aside, this effectively is a very good point, the rooms are SO rooms.

Answer (score 9):

For completeness, [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239226/158100) are the current kick-mute rules:

> **Ban duration**
>
> If this is the first time the user is kicked anywhere (i.e., not necessarily in the same room) in the last 24 hours, the ban will last one minute. If it is the second time, the ban will last five minutes.
>
> If it is the third or more time the user has been kicked within 24 hours, the ban will last for 30 minutes.
>
> *A third kick-ban also raises an auto-flag.*

I think Room Owners can use some help now and then. One of the good aspects of the kick-mute is it's progressive nature. It should however not reset at the third kick. By each next kick the ban duration should be increased. So not limited to your 4th stage but continue. For days/weeks not kicked the ban duration can be lowered again.

I'm not sure if this subsequent kicking should get a moderator involved in the first place. Chat rooms are by nature loosely moderated, if moderated at all and almost anything goes in some rooms.
The problem with kick-mute is that you kick-mute the user, not the message. In the few cases where I had an exchange with a moderator I always had to start with clarifying the context.
I'm not sure if you have the possibility to see the context as a moderator but if not I expect the same mishaps as with NAA flags. That will be valuable time lost without any gain.

Then I have this more philosophical issue: Do we, as a community or Stack Overflow as the company, want chat to be moderated in the first place. In its current nature a Room Owner is nothing more then a user that happens to be able to push some more buttons. They are not elected (although some rooms try to organize some democracy), they are only respected as much as the regulars in the room allow for and in the end they are powerless.

I feel that is exactly what a room owner should be, powerless.

I have put this line in the room guidance of a room I co-own: *In absence of all Room Owners, the members lead by example*. I wholeheartedly believe in that because it is important to guarantee that a chat room creates, adheres and lives a culture that is supported by all its members. I'm much afraid that bringing moderators into the daily RO operation will influence how the room evolves/grows/breaks down.

This doesn't mean as Room Owner that I should be left alone and forgotten. The support I had when needed is very much appreciated and I think prevented a lot of moderator involvement if handled differently. This, however, isn't the kind of moderation that goes easily with one extra kick-mute and mod-flags.

In other words: If you're trying to solve a specific problem, I'm not sure if you need that feature for it.

Comment: I think that if the auto-flag is removed, a "call a moderator" button for Room Owners would be a useful replacement. Then we could request help when we need it, and moderators don't have to waste their time when we don't need their help.

Comment: "I feel that is exactly what a room owner should be, powerless." - Room owners are already powerless. And that's the problem. The mods are getting involved *because* RO's are powerless to moderate themselves.

Comment: @Mysticial yeah, but that complete room is than beyond control. There is no moderation/baby-sitting that will help in that case.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I read somewhere when the "kick-mute" feature was implemented that the auto-flag wasn't just so the mods look at the user _being_ kicked, but also to make sure the feature isn't being abused. That said, if data were to be presented showing that the feature was rarely, if ever, abused, I could see getting rid of the flag for it.

Comment: @rene I disagree with you on that assessment about the Lounge. It can be moderated well - Jon Clements has demonstrated this already. Things only got out of hand recently for other reasons.

Comment: @Mysticial fair enough, fixed